# Learning Zend Framework 2 as a Laravel web developer

Tags: laravel, frameworks, zend-framework2

Let's ignore the discussion on why and why not to use Zend or Laravel.

1. How high would the learning curve be for a Laravel web developer when starting out with Zend Framework? Let's say the developer has about 2 years of experience working with the Laravel, but no pure PHP knowledge.
2. Where and how would you begin to learn a new framework (in this case Zend Framework 2)? Would you just dive in if you have some experience with other frameworks and learn as you go? Or would you follow tutorials? OR simply read the docs? 
   I am fimiliar with some platforms where I learned web and laravel, but not much on Zend2.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Complexity from laravel to Zend Framework would be the explicit use of design patterns that are used in ZF2 and that may be seen as 'magic' in laravel. Php level requirement is not really high, but good knowledge of OOP principle and design pattern is quite mandatory (otherwise you may have a hard time).
ZF2 documentation is not as good as the Laravel documentation and finding well made tutorial may also be hard. 
You may think that it's not worth it, but the use of ZF leads to huge improvement in OOP understanding and also php.
Are there any requirement that prevents you from using ZF3 ?

Comment: I think you should go with zf3 as mentioned by @Unex. Also zf3's tutorial is quite nice for basic crud operations. you can checkout https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/

Comment: Thanks for the insights! Good to know what I need to brush up on in order to get the transition going smooth. I was (re)learning PHP principles, but I think I might have a look at OOP, so that is fresh in my memory. I am aware of the magic Laravel bring, I guess I will see how much once I'm starting. Reason for ZF2 in stead of ZF3 is because I might enroll in an existing product. There is no way I can decide to transfer to go to ZF3, so there's that...

Comment: @Unex Also since there are not many out there, do you know any good learning platforms for ZF2 and/or OOP and such? I believe Jeffrey from Laracast has an OOP bootcamp I can check out. Any more?

Comment: unfortunately not really. You can find on the zend documentation how each of the element work separatly. But there are not many concrete use case that shows how things works together and best practices (you can do some real ugly shit with ZF2 if you don't pay attention). Mainly learned at work by looking how others work and uses it.

Comment: To bad.. But I guess I'll learn while coding then. Still gonna do some OOP courses here and there. Got some time to prepare before I start the project. Thanks for the advice

Comment: in my view point oop = solid principles. also you can check defensive php principles.

Comment: Hope I don't step on anyone's toes with this, but I wrote an extensive tutorial to create a blog from scratch using ZF2 & Doctrine2 (in case you use Doctrine2 with ZF2 of course ;) ). You can find it [here](http://keet.me). It's currently the only thing on the site, writing a similar but way more expanded one for ZF3/Doctrine2 at the moment, but expect that to last me another month or 2 before it goes up and I replace the site at the same time.